# Combine SQL query with variable

Tags: plpgsql, redshift

Redshift support export data to CSV by executing this SQL query.

```sql
unload ('select * from bhuvi') 
to 's3://bhuvi-bucket/folder//user-data.csv' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::1111111:role/myredshiftrole' 
delimiter '|'  GZIP";
```

I have different tables and need to export them to different locations. So 
I have a stored procedure like below. so I can pass the locations in a variable in the future.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_variable()
 LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
DECLARE
   sql text;
   s3_loc text;
   role text;
   deli text;
   query text;
BEGIN
   sql:='select * from bhuvi';
   s3_loc:='s3://bhuvi-bucket/folder/';
   role:='arn:aws:iam::1111111:role/myredshiftrole';
   deli:='|';
   query := "unload (sql) to 's3_loc/user-data.csv' iam_role 'role';
   execute query;
END
$$;
```

but somewhere the syntax is wrong. Im not able to find that. When I call this procedure, im getting this below error.

```sql
test=# call test_variable();
ERROR:  column "unload (sql) to 's3_loc/user-data.csv' iam_role 'role' " does not exist
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT  "unload (sql) to 's3_loc/user-data.csv' iam_role 'role' ""
PL/pgSQL function "test_variable" line 12 at assignment
test=#
```

Comment: It's no clear to me what are you trying to accomplish. Could you add the text of the desired final query?

Comment: @McNets question updated with details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use double quotes for string literals. Do include a single quote in a string literal, it has to be escaped by doubling them:

```
query := 'unload (sql) to ''s3_loc/user-data.csv'' iam_role ''role''';
```

Additionally can't use names of variables from PL/pgSQL in a SQL string. You need to include the *content* of that variable in the query string you build:

```
query := 'unload ('||sql||') to '''||s3_loc||'/user-data.csv'' iam_role '''||role||'''';
```

Comment: Im getting this error. `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "sql"
LINE 1: unload (sql) to 's3_loc/user-data.csv' iam_role 'role'` if my question was not clear,  just updated with the explanation.

Comment: @Bhuvanesh: see my edit

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot, im getting some other error now. But this `query:=` is working great. I'll try to fix other errors which is related to aws.

Comment: I don't know if Redshift supports it, but usually using `format()` is easier when building dynamic SQL